# How to Send Orchestrator Function Result Back To Caller To Update UI

Tags: .net-core, azure-durable-functions

I'm working on on `Azure Orchestrator Function` (Isolated Process) that is called by an `HTTPTrigger` function from a user filling out form/hitting submit in a `React/GraphQL/.NET 7` application. The `Orchestrator Function` could take a couple of hours to run, so I'm wondering how I can send the results of the Orchestrator success/failure asynchronously to update the UI so the user doesn't have to hit refresh every x minutes only to find the function's failed.

Looking at documentation, it doesn't look like `Orchestrator Functions` have this capability built-in and I've seen suggestions like `SignalR` or `Pub/Sub` (we use `Redis` where I work so this may work). I haven't used `SignalR` or set up a `Pub/Sub` system so I'm wondering if this seems like the right way to go to achieve the desired asynchronous UI update or if there's a more efficient/appropriate route to take to tackle this before I dive into either of the above options.