# Is adding "Throw;" an appropriate way to cancel an Orchestrator Function Instance when exception is thrown?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, azure-functions, azure-durable-functions

I have an `Orchestrator Function` (Isolated Worker for `.NET 7` web application) which calls multiple `Activity Functions`. Each of those `Activity Functions` has their own try/catch block in their respective method bodies. So, if an exception is thrown in an Activity Function or in the Orchestrator Function, they all have their own try/catch block, so the exception is handled. According to the bottom of [this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-error-handling?tabs=csharp-inproc):

*"If an orchestrator function fails with an unhandled exception, the details of the exception are logged and the instance completes with a Failed status."*

Because this Function is triggered by users (internal to our company) and could take 1-2+ hours, I want to have the status updated on an exception which users can do by clicking a button (I have a [separate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77293095/how-to-send-orchestrator-function-result-back-to-caller-to-update-ui) about asynchronously updating UI from `Orchestrator Function` if anyone has knowledge of appropriate approach, but that's a separate topic.

So, is it a good idea to just add "Throw" after each exception is handled, including the Orchestrator Function, so the function fails and the status is updated or is that a bad approach/not the best approach?

Comment: Exceptions should ideally only be used for when thing go really wrong and you couldn't expect it. Any normal program flow should be handled by other mechanisms. E.g. loggers or such.

Comment: @JHBonarius That definitely makes sense and I am logging. But, with this Durable Function, each activity function is called in a specific order as returned data from each AF is used as input (for the most part) for the next AF, so an exception in one means the data wasn't read correctly or couldn't be obtained/file was named incorrectly and the program should stop.

Comment: Yeah, that sound like an exception. Maybe I'm just not fully understanding the issue. Does it maybe regard re-throwing an exception after you did some local handling, in order to have higher level handling? That's would be quite common practice.

Comment: @JHBonarius So the "Throw;" I'm thinking of using would go in the necessary catch statements after logging/other local handling. This way, if the exception that needs to stop the whole Orchestrator function instance is thrown in an Activity Function, it gets kicked back up by the Throw to the Orchestrator Catch statement, which then uses "Throw;" again to cause that exception to be unhandled and based on the above documentation link should cause the Orchestrator Function to fail (from an unhandled exception), which is what I'm aiming for so the user can see that it has failed.

Comment: Yes, as I mentioned rethrowing an exception is common practice. ([But should be done properly](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/code-analysis/quality-rules/ca2200).)

Comment: @JHBonarius Perfect! I've rethrown exceptions in non-Azure Function code,  but am still learning best practices for Durable Functions. If you want to set that last comment as the answer with the link, I'll accept it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Rethrowing an exception is common practice, reference [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/code-analysis/quality-rules/ca2200).

I am rethrowing exception in the activity function to get the error in activity function.

My durable function code:

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.DurableTask;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Http;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace FunctionApp4
{
    public static class Function1
    {
        [FunctionName("Function1")]
        public static async Task<List<string>> RunOrchestrator(
            [OrchestrationTrigger] IDurableOrchestrationContext context)
        { 
           try{
                List<string> outputs = new List<string>();
                outputs.Add(await context.CallActivityAsync<string>(nameof(Activity1), ""));
                outputs.Add(await context.CallActivityAsync<string>(nameof(Activity2), ""));

                return outputs;
               }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.StackTrace);
                throw ex;
            }
        }

        [FunctionName(nameof(Activity1))]
        public static string Activity1([ActivityTrigger] string name, ILogger log)
        {
            try
            {
                string str = "Vivek";
                char ch = str[6];
                return str;
            }
            catch (ArithmeticException)
            {
                throw;
            }
        }

        [FunctionName(nameof(Activity2))]
        public static string Activity2([ActivityTrigger] string name, ILogger log)
        {
            try
            {
                string str = "hello";
                char ch = str[5];
                return str;
            }
            catch (ArithmeticException)
            {
                throw;
            }
        }

        [FunctionName("Function1_HttpStart")]
        public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> HttpStart(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", "post")] HttpRequestMessage req,
            [DurableClient] IDurableOrchestrationClient starter,
            ILogger log)
        {
            string instanceId = await starter.StartNewAsync("Function1", null);

            log.LogInformation("Started orchestration with ID = '{instanceId}'.", instanceId);

            return starter.CreateCheckStatusResponse(req, instanceId);
        }
    }
}
```

**`Output:`**

[image]

[image]